# Modelling nonlinear change of outcome in population with unbalanced longitudinal data

Tags: repeated-measures, age, nonlinearity

I would like to flexibly model the development of some continuous outcome of interest as a nonlinear function of age, using longitudinal data with rather strong imbalance (i.e., most individuals cover only a small fraction of the age range of interest with their measurements, although the whole set of measurements is covering the entire range), including an estimate of uncertainty (e.g. confidence bands around the estimated function). Which method would you recommend for this purpose?

I used LOESS to get an idea of the overall trend but I don't know whether the error estimates can account for the correlation present in longitudinal data. Also, I would be interested in both "population average" estimates (such as in marginal models / GEE models, but I don't know if there are any extensions which allow flexible modelling of nonlinear relations) and in "individual-specific" estimates (maybe using Generalized Additive Mixed Models, but since I do not really understand them, I cannot gauge their appropriateness for this situation)

Here's a fictional data set which could be used for illustration purposes (long format, `id` indicates person):

```
structure(list(age = c(30.0972764119853, 34.0860638660555, 36.5100193189136, 
40.6215386946475, 44.7944240312133, 47.9854539944695, 50.654873290655, 
53.4163415280882, 57.0062502367514, 58.9392780029547, 54.9504905488844, 
37.982802378878, 40.5294897533998, 43.8125686579037, 46.8501837190803, 
48.7832114852835, 51.5139967423009, 29.0847380582598, 31.4780105307019, 
32.5519148452593, 35.0065532785333, 38.4123641047009, 35.8043107693473, 
39.3021705367628, 42.3091026175234, 45.9910602674344, 47.4945263078147, 
49.3355051327702, 52.5572180764423, 57.4051289821584, 59.6756695329369, 
61.0257206712376, 53.078828743513, 56.2391757263533, 58.9699609833706, 
60.9950376908216, 38.2896321830372, 43.6284707754082, 49.7343838781772, 
55.533467176787, 57.988105610061, 31.0791317852949, 33.8712830031441, 
37.0623129664002, 39.5169513996742, 42.9227622258419, 47.0649645819917, 
49.396871093602, 50.654873290655, 51.8821925072919, 53.508390469336
), outcome = c(103.49987404484, 107.580821227643, 105.767066924175, 
110.074733394911, 115.062557729448, 131.159627172726, 151.564363086741, 
176.730204047359, 189.879922747502, 198.268536401041, 193.053992778571, 
101.232681165505, 100.325804013771, 104.633470484508, 129.799311445126, 
151.337643798808, 180.357712654295, 105.767066924175, 103.046435468973, 
103.046435468973, 103.953312620707, 105.313628348308, 99.6456461499706, 
111.661768410446, 109.621294819044, 127.758837853724, 153.151398102276, 
177.637081199093, 193.960869930305, 199.175413552775, 191.69367705097, 
201.215887144177, 187.1592912923, 198.948694264842, 193.280712066504, 
196.22806280964, 115.062557729448, 125.945083550256, 187.612729868167, 
186.479133428499, 187.1592912923, 98.0586111344361, 99.8723654379041, 
112.341926274246, 102.592996893106, 117.329750608783, 122.090855655387, 
145.216223024603, 169.248467545554, 186.932572004366, 193.053992778571
), id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "outcome", 
"id"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", "13", "22", 
"32", "42", "52", "14", "23", "33", "43", "53", "62", "71", "81", 
"91", "101", "15", "24", "34", "44", "16", "25", "35", "45", 
"54", "17", "26", "36", "46", "55", "63", "72", "82", "92", "102"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for any help / suggestions!

Comment: A thought: a mixed-effects linear regression model in which age is related to the outcome with a cubic spline and dependency within subjects is captured with a per-subject random intercept. I've written this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not sure if and how you can get confidence bands.